# Will GNOME be updated to 3.30 in Ubuntu 18.04 by itself?

Tags: 18.04, gnome-shell

I know there are already reports on gnome-shell being a massive memory hog, but my question is this: Will gnome 3.30.1 ever hit Ubuntu 18.04, or am I stuck with this memory leakage forever until I upgrade Ubuntu?

Thanks

Edit: I'm asking about this particular instance. Will Ubuntu be updated to gnome 3.30.1 at some point in the future, or will I need to do it manually or upgrade Ubuntu?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you wish to keep 18.04, then you must upgrade Gnome yourself manually (not supported; you're on your own) or learn to love Gnome 3.28.

Ubuntu does NOT upgrade software after release, with only three exceptions: Security patches, Major Bugfix patches, and specific pre-exempted applications (like web browsers) that release often and have short support periods.

Ubuntu uses a *snapshot* system of repo management, not a *rolling* system. Users who want the latest software are expected to release-upgrade their software every six months. That's the choice: Regular upgrades, or no changes. You cannot have both in a deb-based system.

Developers are working to move Gnome from a deb-based to a Snap-based system, which would solve your problem - the 6-month releases wouldn't matter, and you could upgrade Gnome anytime after the Snap is packaged. However, this project is still in the very early stages, and not likely to be ready for you to test for another year or two.